# uncaught reference error in snowflake function

Tags: javascript, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting error with below code, please advise:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnParseString (STRINGTOP VARCHAR,DELIMITER1 VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
language javascript
AS
$$ 
var sql_A = `SELECT CASE WHEN charindex(DELIMITER1,STRINGTOP) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`;
var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:sql_A});
var rs = statement.execute();
return rs;
$$;
```

When I do > select function('this is test',' ');

Getting below error:

```
JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: snowflake is not defined in FNPARSESTRING at 'var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:sql_A});' position 16 stackstrace: FNPARSESTRING line: 3
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**[Binding variables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html#label-stored-procedures-binding-variables)** should be used to pass the value into SQL statement:

```
-- though it cannot be used in JS UDF
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnParseString (STRINGTOP VARCHAR,DELIMITER1 VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
language javascript
AS
$$ 
var sql_A = `SELECT CASE WHEN charindex(:1, :2) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`;
var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:sql_A,
                                           binds:[DELIMITER1,STRINGTOP]});
var rs = statement.execute();
return rs;
$$;
```

---

Alternative approach is to use SQL UDF:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnParseString (STRINGTOP VARCHAR,DELIMITER1 VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
language sql
AS
$$ 
CASE WHEN charindex(STRINGTOP , DELIMITER1) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
$$;
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, appreciate it. I will be using language javascript for this, so by using binding variables I am getting another error. Here is my code:```var sql_A = "SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(:1,:2)= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;"
var statement = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:sql_A,binds:[DELIMITER1,STRINGTOP]});
var rs = statement.execute();
return rs;``` with error as ```Compilation of SQL UDF failed: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 4 unexpected 'sql_A'. syntax error line 3 at position 0 unexpected 'var'.``` ... Also,  can I avoid binding variables?

Comment: @user3204086 `var sql_A = "` why is this version using `"` isnstead of `?

Comment: tried just to overcome if any error gets fixed, keeping it as var sql_A=` also returns the same error.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot write select statements in JavaScript UDF  and need to build Stored Prod based off JS and below is same :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fnParseString1(STRINGTOP VARCHAR,DELIMITER1 VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var cmd = "SELECT CASE WHEN charindex(:1, :2) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
          {
          sqlText: cmd,
          binds: [DELIMITER1,STRINGTOP]
          }
          );
var result1 = stmt.execute();
result1.next()
return result1.getColumnValue(1);
$$
;
call fnParseString1('this is test','');
```

[image: Output]

Comment: hi @Anand, I am writing function as I need to parse strings through it and the function will be called in a snowflake procedure.